# Escape special characters in JSON string

Tags: json, perl, escaping, character

I have Perl script which contains variable `$env->{'arguments'}`, this variable should contain a JSON object and I want to pass that JSON object as argument to my other external script and run it using backticks.

Value of `$env->{'arguments'}` before escaping:

```
$VAR1 = '{"text":"This is from module and backslash \\ should work too"}';
```

Value of `$env->{'arguments'}` after escaping:

```
$VAR1 = '"{\\"text\\":\\"This is from module and backslash \\ should work too\\"}"';
```

Code:

```
print Dumper($env->{'arguments'});
escapeCharacters(\$env->{'arguments'});
print Dumper($env->{'arguments'});

my $command = './script.pl '.$env->{'arguments'}.'';
my $output = `$command`;
```

Escape characters function:

```
sub escapeCharacters
{
    #$env->{'arguments'} =~ s/\\/\\\\"/g;
    $env->{'arguments'} =~ s/"/\\"/g;
    $env->{'arguments'} = '"'.$env->{'arguments'}.'"';
}
```

I would like to ask you what is correct way and how to parse that JSON string into valid JSON string which I can use as argument for my script.

Comment: See also [String::ShellQoute](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::ShellQuote). Another alternative that avoids handing your argument over to the shell (and hence the need for escaping) is to write it to a tempfile and then pass the filename of the tempfile as an argument to your script instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reinventing a [wheel](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?String::ShellQuote).

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my $cmd = shell_quote('./script.pl', $env->{arguments});
my $output = `$cmd`;
```

Alternatively, there's a number of IPC:: modules you could use instead of `qx`. For example,

```
use IPC::System::Simple qw( capturex );

my $output = capturex('./script.pl', $env->{arguments});
```

Because you have at least one argument, you could also use the following:

```
my $output = '';
open(my $pipe, '-|', './script.pl', $env->{arguments});
while (<$pipe>) {
   $output .= $_;
}

close($pipe);
```

---

Note that current directory isn't necessarily the directory that contains the script that executing. If you want to executing `script.pl` that's in the same directory as the currently executing script, you want the following changes:

Add

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
```

and replace

```
'./script.pl'
```

with

```
"$RealBin/script.pl"
```

Comment: I tried to add docker command to that shell_quote and I get: `cd /home/user/system/!project/_addons/Ext/PHPtest && docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/app -w /app php php hello.php` : not found

Comment: What exactly you were hopping to accomplish by passing a shell command to `shell_quote`?!?! It'll produce `'cd /home/user/system/!project/_addons/Ext/PHPtest && docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/app -w /app php php hello.php'`, which you apparently tried to execute as a shell command, which would try to execute a file named `cd /home/user/system/!project/_addons/Ext/PHPtest && docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/app -w /app php php hello.php`. That this file is "not found" is an understatement!

Comment: @ikegame but you don't understand me, that command is valid and file exists if I run it only by backsticks, but I just changed it, I wrapped only file and arguments into `shell_quote` and it works.

Comment: No, there's no doubt what I said is correct. There's no directory named `cd<space>`, much less a file at the path `cd /home...`. You're getting the error because you executed the shell command `'cd /home...'` instead of the shell command  `cd /home...`. That said, even though I can tell you what you did and why that's wrong from what little you told me, I have no idea why you did that, or what you were trying to achieve. But here's not the place for that. If you have a new question, post a new Question.

Answer (score 1):

Piping it to your second program rather than passing it as an argument seems like it would make more sense (and be a lot safer).

test1.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;

undef $/;

my $data = decode_json(<>);
print Dumper($data);
```

test2.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use IPC::Open2;
use JSON;

my %data = ('text' => "this has a \\backslash", 'nums' => [0,1,2]);
my $json = JSON->new->encode(\%data);

my ($chld_out, $chld_in);
print("Executing script\n");
my $pid = open2($chld_out, $chld_in, "./test1.pl");
print $chld_in "$json\n";
close($chld_in);
my $out = do {local $/; <$chld_out>};
waitpid $pid, 0;
print(qq~test1.pl output =($out)~);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I would like to really use arguments, because then I could call that script with docker command.